# How to upgrade couchdb 0.11.0 to 1.2.0

Tags: couchdb

I have a database on couchdb 0.11.0 in a debian 6 box - I have been struggling to transfer this database to another debian (7) box with couchdb 1.2.0.  The error seems to be around 'content type ' specification.
The apache-couchdb documentation talks about 'simply applying a patch to the replicator to allow content type: application/json'.  But how do you do this?  Any help deeply appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just copy the db file instead of using the replication. By default (on Centos) this file it can be find under `/var/lib/couchdb/` path. Once you copy it to couchdb 1.2.0 folder it should notice the old database file format and upgrade it.

Note: You might have to restart the database to make it notice the new file, although I'm not sure if this step is necessary.

Comment: Worked very well - many thanks.  Just need to make sure the database is owned by couchdb and group couchdb